# Can't figure out why my CSV file is not converting to a string when adding to trie node

Tags: java, csv, filereader, trie, opencsv

Reading in a basic csv file, the first line,(csv), is "abacus,,,,,,,, trust,,". Trying to take out the commas and add the two words to some sort of list or array. The issue starts when I try to reference the first word on the line trie.search("abacus"). Still very new to coding but this one has me stuck.

```
try {
    while ((csv = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = csv.split(",");
        System.out.println(csv);
        if (words.length == 2) {
            String word = words[0].trim();
            int code = 0;
            trie.insert(word, code);
        }
    }
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        
System.out.println(trie.search("abacus"));
```

I tried inserting the word in several different ways within the word parameter but each time it does not work unless I type "abacus" as the parameter.

Comment: `The issue starts when I try to reference the first word on the line trie.search("abacus")`. How? Can you show us how you tried to do it other than hard-coding "abacus"?

Comment: Why are most of your fields empty? Splitting like that will still leave you with all the fields, empty or not, as array elements so the array will always be of length nine. That's just how CSV works

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have the following *if-conditional*.

```java
if (words.length == 2)
```

Your *split* method call is going to return *9* elements.

I believe what you are intending to use is a *",+"*, as you're *split* parameter.
The *[split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* parameter is evaluated as a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Which, in this case, a plus character is going to assimilate 1 or more of the character which precedes it.

For example, here are the array elements when a single comma is used.

```
0 abacus
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8  trust
```

And, here are the elements when a *",+"* is used.

```
0 abacus
1  trust
```